# How to write a bot that reads in javascript cookies

Tags: java, browser, bots

Can browser extensions be programmed to browse a series of websites, filling out get and post requests automatically; given that rhino is a way of implementing javascript in a java program, would it be more practical to build a java bot implemented with rhino or a bot with browser extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) is an extension that does what you like though the scripting language is JavaScript not Java.

> Chickenfoot is a Firefox extension that puts a programming environment in the browser's sidebar so you can write scripts to manipulate web pages and automate web browsing. In Chickenfoot, scripts are written in a superset of Javascript that includes special functions specific to web tasks.